# Error running svn commands on cmd line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Im trying to run the svn copy command as below.

```
svn copy https://rb-svn1.in.company.com/svn/Project500/branches \
https://rb-1.in.company.com/svn/cust04/Project500/tags/V1.xx \
-m "Dummy test version V1.xx tag"
```

But i receive error msg saying that :

```
svn: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening here ?

Vatsa

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?  Looks like the server and domain name differ in the svn copy command: rb-svn1.in.company.com vs. rb-1.in.company.com

Comment: faulty shell link as possible error source: see http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=340657

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered this same error when I was trying to create a tag from the command line. The mistake I made is that I have put a space in the tag name.

A few things you need to keep in mind while creating TAGS in SVN:

1. A tag is always created from a TRUNK 
    *(because that is, essentially, a "Working Copy" and post the tag creation a revision number is being created)*
2. You should NEVER put a space between words for a "tagname". 
   *I also hope you are not putting the backslash "\" while you're typing the full command*

The correct syntax like this: 
svn copy https://.../trunk https://.../tags/"tagname without spaces" -m "Release 1x.x of YourProductName"

This was my $0.02. I hope you find this helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like SVN dooesn't need nither -m nor -r option. So it will copy your repository from one place to another one.

This note is taken from 'svn help copy':
    URL -> URL:  complete server-side copy;  used to branch and tag

Comment: They might need the -m option if they have pre-commit hook that mandates a commit message.

Comment: Without the -m option svn copy fails with this:

svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found